# Arduino as HID keyboard change PID and VID

Tags: arduino, usb, avr, bootloader, hid

I just implemented an Arduino keyboard program on an Arduino Leonardo or a Pro Micro and its working fine but, I want it to appear as a keyboard only and not showing it as an Arduino on a new computer without Arduino drivers. How to change the PID and VID of the board to make it appear as a keyboard only?

Here is a picture that explains my problem.

[image]